# Optimizing JMeter scripts for low end servers

Tags: jmeter

I'm have a simple JMeter script with 300 threads that checks a list of 30 static URLs with a 2 second delay between requests.

I'm hitting CPU usage limit on my machine (EC2 Large Server).

Any idea on which switch and levers have the greatest impact on server resources?
For example:
Number of threads
Delay between requests
Number of steps (URLs) in script
Versions of JMeter (2.9 vs 2.10)

Thanks
Ophir

Comment: Question is too ambiguous , what is the script ?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that you've

1. Disabled all listeners
2. Running JMeter in non-GUI mode, i.e. via command-line, Ant, Maven or whatever
3. Your Post Processors (if any) aren't resource-consuming, i.e. you're trying to extract something with Regular Expression Extractor from immense output.
4. You're using the latest version of JMeter and Java (JMeter 2.10 is better than 2.9)
5. You're using 64-bit Java with enough heap space provided
6. You're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/42699-jmeter-best-practices)

If you problem still persists, you can consider looking into following options:

- Profile Java process running JMeter to detect what classes are most CPU-consuming
- Use several "lesser" EC2 instances with 1 JMeter "master" and 2-3 slaves

Answer (score 0):

If you have static URLs, just:

- Use a CSV DataSet which will contain these URLs
- One HTTP Request Sampler that will use it

With a large Server, 300 threads is really nothing.

You may read :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
- http://www.dzone.com/links/see_how_to_make_jmeter_run_thousands_of_threads_w.html